# how to transform this json file to table?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have this json file with this structure :

```
  [{
     "Marque": "VOLKSWAGEN",   "Modeles": {
    "UP": {
      "Basique": {
        "Manuelle": [
          {
            "Finition": "1.0 l move up",
            "Prix": 42980,
            "Date_Scraping": {
              "$date": "2020-10-16T11:21:30.116Z"
            }
          },
          {
            "Finition": "1.0 l move up",
            "Prix": 42980,
            "Date_Scraping": {
              "$date": "2020-10-17T08:33:15.099Z"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "Last_Scraping_Date": {
        "$date": "2020-11-03T06:35:15.614Z"
      }
    }}}]
```

I want to transform it to have a result like the picture below
[result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUcvu.png)
Any idea how to deal with it?
PS : the json file is from a mongodb data

Comment: What python code have you tried so far?

Comment: hello @zmike tablib library ,pandas.io.json

Comment: will you please provide the code you tried?

Comment: from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import pandas as pd

pd.json_normalize(data_nested, 
                          record_path='Modeles', 
                          meta=['Marque'])
        
#data_nested is a dict containing exactly like the json file .

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. This does require Excel though.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a

Edit with Free Version:
https://konklone.io/json/

Comment: thank you for your response, but the problem is that option is a payment option with office360

Comment: thank you , i checked already and most of converter online.